# Using SED/AWK to replace letters after a certain position

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with words (1 word per line). I need to censor all letters in the word, except the first five, with a `*`.

Ex.

`Authority` -> `Autho****`

I'm not very sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are lucky, all you need is

```
sed 's/./*/6g' file
```

When I originally posted this, I believed this to be reasonably portable; but as per @ghoti's comment, it is not.

Comment: Error: `sed: 1: "s/./*/6g": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags` in FreeBSD and macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'substr($_, 5) =~ s/./*/g' -- file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) returns a substring of the given string starting at the given position.
- `s/./*/g` replaces any character with an asterisk. The `g` means the substitution will happen as many times as possible, not just once, so all the characters will be replaced.

In some versions of `sed`, you can specify which substitution should happen by appending a number to the operation:

```
sed -e 's/./*/g6'
```

This will replace all (again, because of `g`) characters, starting from the 6th position.

Comment: But I can use only sed or awk for this, it's a challenge given to me

Comment: @VijayrajS then show your attempted sed/awk code and we can help you with issues..

Comment: @choroba as far as I know, that is specific to [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).. `the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and then match and replace all matches from the numberth on`

Comment: Thank you @choroba

Comment: @VijayrajS You could accept the answer if it helped `:-)`  That is the SO way of saying thank you. \@choroba, `g6` idea looks brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a portable solution for `sed`:

```
$ echo abcdefghi | sed -e 's/\(.\{5\}\)./\1*/;:x' -e 's/\*[a-z]/**/;t x'
abcde****
```

Here's how it works:

- `'s/\(.\{5\}\)./\1*/'` - preserve the first five characters, replacing the 6th with an asterisk.
- `':x'` - set a "label", which we can branch back to later.
- `'s/\*[a-z]/**/ - '` - substitute the letter following an asterisk with an asterisk.
- `'t x'` - if the last substitution succeeded, jump back to the label "x".

This works equally well in GNU and BSD sed.

Of course, adjust the regexes to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

***Solution 1st:*** `awk` solution with `substr` and `gensub`.

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,5) gensub(/./,"*","g",substr($0,6))}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk 'NF{len=length($0);if(len>5){i=6;while(i<=len){val=val?val "*":"*";i++};print substr($0,1,5) val};val=i=""}'  Input_file
Autho****
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now. Adding explanation with it too now.

```
awk '
NF{                         ##Checking if a line is NON-empty.
  len=length($0);           ##Taking length of the current line into a variable called len here.
  if(len>5){                ##Checking if length of current line is greater than 5 as per OP request. If yes then do following.
    i=6;                    ##creating variable named i whose value is 6 here.
    while(i<=len){          ##staring a while loop here which runs from value of variable named i value to till the length of current line.
      val=val?val "*":"*";  ##creating variable named val here whose value will be concatenated to its own value, it will add * to its value each time.
      i++                   ##incrementing variable named i value with 1 each time.
};
    print substr($0,1,5) val##printing value of substring from 1st letter to 5th letter and then printing value of variable val here too.
};
val=i=""                    ##Nullifying values of variable val and i here too.
}
' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: instead of length and while, why not use just substr and gsub/gensub?

Comment: @Sundeep, done sir. Added solution with `gensub` and `substr` now.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just use sed for this (see [@triplee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367411/1745001)) but if you want to do it in awk it'd be:

```
$ awk '{t=substr($0,1,5); gsub(/./,"*"); print t substr($0,6)}' file
Autho****
```

or with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,5) gensub(/./,"*","g",substr($0,6))}' file
Autho****
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible and quite straightforward with `sed`:

```
sed 's/./\*/6;:loop;s/\*[^\*]/\**/;/\*[^\*]/b loop' file_to_censor.txt
```

**output:**

[image]

**explanation:**

```
s/./\*/6           #replace the 6th character of the chain by *
:loop              #define an label for the goto
s/\*[^\*]/\**/     #replace * followed by non * char by **
/\*[^\*]/b loop    #then loop until it does not exist a * followed by a non * char
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward sed solution (that does not require GNUsed):

```
sed -e :a -e 's/^\(.....\**\)[^*]/\1*/;ta' filename
```